# java.sql.SQLException: Field 'register_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've writing a rest service using spring boot and spring data jpa.
I got problem when inserting a data to database. I got searched but not figure out the problem.

So, I have a table in Mysql called `user`.

This is the DDL:

```
'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'registerId' INT NULL,
'genderId' INT NULL,
'cityId' INT NULL,
'firstName' VARCHAR(255) NULL,
'lastName' VARCHAR(255) NULL,
'username' VARCHAR(255) NULL,
'age' INT(2) NULL,
'email' VARCHAR(100) NULL,
'isNotificationAllowed' BIT(1) NULL,
'isBlocked' BIT(1) NULL,
'isActive' BIT(1) NULL,
'createdAt' TIMESTAMP NULL,
'updatedAt' TIMESTAMP NULL,
```

And this is the Entity represent those columns in java project.

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "registerId", nullable = true)
    private int registerId;

    @Column(name = "genderId", nullable = true)
    private Integer genderId;

    @Column(name = "cityId", nullable = true)
    private Integer cityId;

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = true)
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "isNotificationAllowed", nullable = true)
    private boolean isNotificationAllowed;

    @Column(name = "isBlocked", nullable = true)
    private boolean isBlocked;

    @Column(name = "isActive", nullable = true)
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "createdAt", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updatedAt", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp updatedAt;
}
```

So, when I run the service via Postman, it shows an sql on console like this 
`insert into user (age, city_id, created_at, email, first_name, gender_id, is_active, is_blocked, is_notification_allowed, last_name, register_id, updated_at, username, id)`.

As you figure out entity names are different than the column names in database. For ex: `cityId` in my POJO transformed `city_id` in sql. So, I've search it and found that there is a bug in @Column annotation. It is not working as we expected.

Please look at : Here's [a link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2129).

So,to be able to solve this problem I've added

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Then restarted the application and the it seems column mapping has resolved:

```
Hibernate: 
 insert 
 into
     user
     (age, cityId, createdAt, email, firstName, genderId, isActive, isBlocked, isNotificationAllowed, lastName, registerId, updatedAt, username, id) 
 values
     (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

But at the end of the logs, there is an error thrown. It says:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'register_id' doesn't have a default value
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
```

I don't understand where the fieds `register_id` exits. It doesn't exist in database or entity.

When I don't send `registerId` as parameter in the request, it says `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'registerId' cannot be null`. Also didn't figure out that message. Because it is nullable in database and defined nullable in entity.

Comment: If the field names on the Java entity match the column name you don't need to add the `name=registerId` part to your `@Column` annotation, you can just do `@Column(nullable = true)`.

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` did you put these properties?

Comment: @JonathanJohx yes, I've explain it in the question.

Comment: Does it work? what errors do you have? those errors that you added this question?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I've explain it step by step in the question. Yes the error is still exist.

Comment: @clav your comment doesn't explain the problem. It doesn't change the result. But you are right it is boilerplate.

Comment: try removing `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl` and keeping the physical strategy

Comment: It's a long shot, but if youy use Eclipse, project->clean usually helps in such a mysterious cases :)

Comment: @Selindek I've using Intellij and try File -> Invalidate Caches, doesn't help :)

Comment: @clav it is not true. When I remove the configurations, it still writes sql like this, `insert into user (age, city_id, created_at, email, first_name, gender_id, is_active, is_blocked, is_notification_allowed, last_name, register_id, updated_at, username, id) ` which is not true mapping.

Comment: What version of Spring data are you using?

Comment: I've using spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `registerId` property is defined as `int`, not as `Integer`. the appropriate column can be `null` in the database, but that `null` value cannot be converted to `int`. Change it to `Integer`.

Comment: I've changed it data type but still the same error thrown.

Comment: Updated the question with new case at the end of the question explanation.